# ps2pdf - white margins added from .ps to .pdf

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Here is my problem. Through a software used to make plots called xmgrace, I obtain a .ps file. From that file, doing

```
 ps2pdf file.ps
```

converts the PostScript file to a PDF. However, during that conversion, white margins appears (mostly to the right,as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FSt1.jpg)).
I have tried to add the option -dEPSCrop after ps2pdf, but to no avail unfortunately.
Do you have any idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, this is a platform for asking questions related to programming. Your question does not include and code. So, please use [other networks of stack exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) or find another platform to ask your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the notification. I just edited my question, it seems I used the Blockcode instead of the Code Sample tag. However, if the bash code I wrote in my question is not considered as code, where should I ask this question? Thank you.